# How to mount a remote (over SSH) directory to be available like a local directory (incl. in shell, not just in Gnome)?

Tags: filesystem, ssh, mount, remote-access, file-sharing

I've got my files (mostly text/code, nothing of heavy like videos etc.) in a directory on a remote server which I can only access by means of SSH. Can I mount it on my laptop to use it seamlessly from all the applications (incl command-line ones)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes indeed, you can! It's called sshfs. [Here's](http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/10/28/how-to-mount-a-remote-ssh-filesystem-using-sshfs/) a little tutorial.

The basic idea is:

1. Install `sshfs`

   ```
   sudo apt install sshfs
   ```
2. Mount the remote directory

   ```
   sshfs user@host:/path/to/remote /path/to/local/mount/point
   ```

You now have the remote directory `/path/to/remote` available at `/path/to/local/mount/point`.

Comment: sshfs is great. In fact, it's the only remote-file-access method Ubuntu offers that I find works reliably.